# react-xml-parser: How to define variable xmlText

Tags: reactjs, xml

In my React website I want to read a XML file and show the data in a HTML table. I found the [react-xml-parser](https://github.com/matanshiloah/xml-parser) on Github and it seems to be suitible for my needs.

I have created a new React project using `npx create-react-app my-app` command. Inside my project I have created a file named `components\PhysicalFlow.js` which will parse the XML file. The XML file is located at another server http://someserver.com/GetFlow.xml

The manual for react-xml-parser says that the variable `xmlText` contains the XML data. However I dont know how to get the XML into that variable using React.

```
var XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser');
var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xmlText);    // Assume xmlText contains the example XML
console.log(xml);
console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName('Name'));
```

How can I get a XML file into the variable xmlText? I tried using axios but I could only load json files with it.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import PhysicalFlow from './components/PhysicalFlow.js';


function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <header>
        <p>Read data from XML</p>
      </header>

      <main>
        <PhysicalFlow />
      </main>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
/* Header ------------------------------------- */
header {
  background-color: #3c3f41;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
header > p {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-weight: bold;
}

main {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**components/PhysicalFlow.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PhysicalFlow extends React.Component {
  state = {
    flows: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    var XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser');
    var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xmlText);    // Assume xmlText contains the example XML
    console.log(xml);
    console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName('Name'));
  
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
       <tr>
        {
          this.state.flows
            .map(flow =>
              <td>{flow}</td>
            )
        }
       </tr>
      </table>
    )
  };
};
```

**GetFlow.xml**

```
<ArrayOfPhysicalFlowMapFlowItem
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestApi.Models.Map">
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE4</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DE</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-615.0000</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DE</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DK1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>1937.7101</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NL</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DK1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-700.2973</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE3</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DK1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-205.4711</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DE</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DK2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>485.0900</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DK1</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>DK2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-294.6793</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>RU</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>EE</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>217.8391</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>EE</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>FI</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>1029.7000</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE1</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>FI</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-1278.4263</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE3</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>FI</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-80.9949</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>BY</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LT</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-29.6805</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>RU</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LT</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-344.8353</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE4</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LT</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-223.6128</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>EE</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LV</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-577.7626</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>LT</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LV</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>609.2625</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>RU</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>LV</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-155.7198</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO2</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-305.2253</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO3</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-334.4333</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO5</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-2012.5555</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE3</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-289.5312</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DE</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>913.9307</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DK1</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>724.0790</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>EN</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>1050.0000</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NL</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>0.7187</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO5</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-465.0420</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO4</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO3</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-662.4810</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>NO5</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO3</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-39.2362</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE2</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO3</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-134.8104</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>FI</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>48.8062</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>RU</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>0.0000</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE1</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>286.3229</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE2</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>NO4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>45.4269</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>LT</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>PL</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-0.1000</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>FI</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>RU</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>947.5674</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE2</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>SE1</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>993.0376</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE3</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>SE2</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>6201.2705</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>SE4</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>SE3</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>2865.5781</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>DK2</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>SE4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>-970.9890</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
<PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
    <InAreaElspotId>PL</InAreaElspotId>
    <MeasureDate>1645954020000</MeasureDate>
    <OutAreaElspotId>SE4</OutAreaElspotId>
    <Value>426.9780</Value>
</PhysicalFlowMapFlowItem>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113236/12579290?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Huzaifa. No sadly it doesnt answer my question. I want to get an external XML file into React and show the results in ta table.